# Makefile does not detect the rules I set

Tags: python, makefile

I Created a makefile, and declared 2 rules, test and clean, when I try to run the make it does not recognize the rules and I get an error.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
PYTHON = python3

test: test.in
    $(PYTHON) process.py $< out.txt

clean:
    rm -f out.txt
```

I try to run either make clean or make test, and I get the following error:
`make: *** No rule to make target` test'.  Stop.`

I am in the correct directory, and here is the listing of the directory contents:
 `% ls Makefile.mk     process.py      test.in`

Any help would be appreciated as it is my first time creating a makefile

Comment: Are you sure the file `test.in` exists in your current directory?  Please [edit] your question to provide a listing of the directory contents.

Comment: The behavior you describe is not possible given the information you've provided so there must be something you haven't told us.  It's definitely not that you're missing `test.in`: if it was you'd get an error that you can't build `test.in`, not `test`.  As G.M. suggests please show the results of `ls` from the same directory you run `make`.  Remember that make looks for makefiles named `Makefile` or `makefile`, but not other forms like `MakeFile` or `makefile.txt` or whatever (assuming you're using a case-sensitive filesystem).

Comment: As per the comment by MadScientist `make` won't automatically find and use your makefile because you've given it a non-standard name.  Either rename it appropriately or specify its name explicitly in your command line using `make -f Makefile.mk` .

Comment: That fixed it, than you!

Answer (score 0):

Makefile was not named correctly, I thought it needed a file extension, but was wrong.